# Flutter Basics: My app bar color is not changing

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(RecipeApp());
}

class RecipeApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Recipe Calculator',
      theme: theme.copyWith(
        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(
          primary: Colors.grey,
          secondary: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),

      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Recipe Calculator'),
    );
  }
}
```

> This is the current code and above is the current output as per the code, the color remains blue and white instead of grey and black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running on my emulator using your code it works, try restarting your app completely.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(RecipeApp());
}

class RecipeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Recipe Calculator',
      theme: theme.copyWith(
        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(
          primary: Colors.grey,
          secondary: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Recipe Calculator'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final title;
  const MyHomePage({this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked the issue was this code:

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

 @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

I changed the above code with yours now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you ,I think you can used **Scaffold** Widget refer AppBar class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) and refer Scaffold class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,//change color on your need
        title: Text(
          'BottomNavigationBar Sample',
        ),
      ),
      body:Container(),//or your widget
);
```

Your result screen-> [image]